# Calling server event of a button in ASP.NET from Javascript

Tags: asp.net, javascript, postback

I have a  button, I need to display a pop-up in javascript. So on its client click I call a javascript function which does that.

if user clicks "yes", I need to do a post back and call buttons server side click event, here is what I am doing inside the javascript function

```
__doPostBack(deleteLinkButton, 'Click'); 

' Where deleteLinkButton is a variable that has client Id of the button.
```

Postback happens but it does not go in the click handler for that button.

What can be wrong?

Comment: Ever find a solution to this?  I'm running into the same issue.

Comment: You need to use the name attribute rather than the id attribute of the rendered input tag.

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
__doPostBack('deleteLinkButton', 'Click');
```

Comment: I am sorry for not explaining this in the question, deleteLinkButton is the variable that has the button client id.

Answer (score 1):

Can be done like this:

```
document.getElementById('<%= Button.ClientID %>').click();
```